# What is the "canonical" size of The Hulk?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, avengers

I've noticed that in the recent Hulk movies his size varies from movie to movie. I've heard, but don't know for a fact that the size of the Hulk seemed to change during the 2003 Eric Bana Hulk movie.

In the Ed Norton version he seems to be 2-3 stories tall. But in the more recent Avengers movie I'd say he was more like 2-3 meters. I can see why he is made smaller in this movie, since he was going to go toe-to-toe with Thor.

So, **is there a size that is ever mentioned in the comics? Or do the comics leave room for his size to change to fit the situation?**

Comment: He wasn't 2-3 stories tall. In the scene where he jumps out of the covered bridge at the school, they're using a low angle looking up from the ground right at his feet. If he was 2-3 stories tall, his head would have been scraping the ceiling of the soda plant in Brazil. He was probably around 7'6" - 8' tall in The Incredible Hulk.

Comment: I remember there being a good shot of him staring down Blonsky right before he front snap kicks him into a tree and he looks to be about a foot taller than Tim Roth so I'd guess he was probably 7'

Comment: In the Ed Norton hulk he seems to be about 10ft tall http://www.pghcitypaper.com/imager/the-hulk-shows-his-metal-to-blonsky-tim-roth/b/original/1390161/e745/25_film2_hulk.jpg

Comment: very bloody huge.

Comment: @krillgar,I have not seen the movie for a couple of years. But you are correct it was a camera angle thing.

Comment: @Mauro, Thanks.

Comment: In the picture posted above by Mauro, Hulk looks to be about 8' or so, assuming Blonsky is around 6'.

Comment: @Omegacron Tim Roth is 5'7"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [marvel.com](http://marvel.com/characters/25/hulk) here are the various heights:

> 5' 9½" (Banner); 
> 6'6" (gray Hulk);
>  **7' – 8' (green/savageHulk)**; 
> 7'6"
>   (green/Professor Hulk)

Also, it is known that **the madder Bruce gets, the stronger the Hulk gets**. If I'm not mistaken, that affects the size as well. So, the madder Bruce is, the bigger the Hulk is.

Comment: Barely tall enough to stare into Yao Ming's eyes... Hate to admit it, but I'm kind of disappointed.

Comment: _"The madder, the bigger"_ Now there's a conversation stopper if ever I heard one ;)

Comment: This is really what I was hoping for, thanks @Shev. He may not be as tall as I hoped, but I glad my theory of him changing size for the situation is not totally wrong.